# How to externally listen calls from clients to the ASMX web service server?

Tags: web-services, asmx

We have an ASMX web service, the hosting server accepts API calls from clients. 
We need to use these calls and the data for some standalone analysis. 
How can we listen all the API calls and get the data? 
For some reason we don't have permit to update codes in the web service host. Need to listen in a standalone utility.
Searched in the internet, we couldn't have two server listening to the same port.
Thanks!

Comment: is your web service hosted in IIS?

Comment: One is hosted in IIS. Another is hosted in windows service.